# Is it possible to make Netlogo communicate with L-system studio?

Tags: netlogo

Is it possible to make Netlogo communicate with other modelling systems? I would want to make a plant in L-system studio, and then ask Netlogo to read and display this plant in Netlogo world? Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know L-system studio, but your best bet is to look into writing a NetLogo extension that somehow either speaks directly with L-system studio, or that somehow takes data that L-system studio has written to a file, and imports that into NetLogo. You can read about the NetLogo Extensions API here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API Alternatively embed both NetLogo and L-system studio in a Java app, and have them communiate through that. You'd want to use the Controlling API for that: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API

Comment: @ArthurHjorth, your comment would be perfectly good as an answer

Comment: @SethTisue Oh great, I'm still not sure when it's an answer, or when it's a comment. Copy/pasting it to answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know L-system studio, but your best bet is to look into writing a NetLogo extension that somehow either speaks directly with L-system studio, or that somehow takes data that L-system studio has written to a file, and imports that into NetLogo. You can read about the NetLogo Extensions API [here](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API). Alternatively embed both NetLogo and L-system studio in a Java app, and have them communicate through that. You'd want to use the [Controlling API](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API) for that.